# Installing Eclipse IDEs for Java and C/C++

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, eclipse, c++

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 and want to install the Eclipse IDE for both Java and C/C++ programming. I installed the separate installation files from their official website. I followed this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse). (The top answer)

The steps helped me install the Java IDE but I don't know what changes I should make to the procedure to install the C/C++ IDE.

Another thread [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2142374), recommended to install `eclipse-cdt` but the Eclipse version installed is outdated. (Doesn't allow me to install Pydev)

I have TWO questions:

1. Can the C/C++ libraries be downloaded from within eclipse, like Pydev?
2. If not, how do I install both IDEs without interfering with each other?

P.S. I commented this query in the first thread but got no reply, that is why I'm asking a fresh question!

Comment: easiest way is to use the eclipse installer
see this answer
http://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your first question

No, you can't download the C/C++ libraries from within eclipse, like Pydev.

---

### Your second question

1. Install Eclipse JEE and Eclipse C/C++ in separate folders in `/opt` eg:

   ```
   /opt/eclipse-cpp
   /opt/eclipse-jee
   ```
2. Create two different desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`

   - `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse_cpp.desktop`

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Encoding=UTF-8
     Version=1.0
     Type=Application
     Name=Eclipse C++
     Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
     Icon=eclipse
     Exec=/opt/eclipse-cpp/eclipse
     StartupNotify=true
     StartupWMClass=Eclipse-CPP
     ```
   - `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse_jee.desktop`

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Encoding=UTF-8
     Version=1.0
     Type=Application
     Name=Eclipse JEE
     Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
     Icon=eclipse
     Exec=/opt/eclipse-jee/eclipse
     StartupNotify=true
     StartupWMClass=Eclipse-Java
     ```
3. During the first start of both Eclipse distributions, select a different workspace folder for each of them, eg

   ```
   workspace-cpp
   workspace-jee
   ```

   Alternatively you can change the workspace folder in Eclipse itself via <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Switch Workspace</kbd>

Now you can use both distributions in parallel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can install eclipse from the software center and then open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

Comment: Would that not be an attempt to install Eclipse twice?

Comment: No. it's just add cdt to the existing exlipse

Comment: These solutions wouldn't work as I am working software downloaded from the official site.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is to use umake because you'll get the very latest build. `sudo apt install` will only get you the build that's currently available from the repository, which could be surprisingly old.

To install umake:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

Then to get eclipse (2018/19) at the moment:

```
umake ide eclipse
```

For java EE:

```
umake ide eclipse-jee
```

For C/C++:

```
umake ide eclipse-cpp
```

For PHP:

```
umake ide eclipse-php
```

http://linuxhackr.com/eclipse-ide-on-ubuntu/