# Integrate Java into Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I just downloaded an Eclipse mirror (Kepler) for C/C++ developers. My question is how I could integrate Java into Eclipse. I already have java JDK/JRE installed on my computer - so I only need a method to integrate this nicely into Eclipse. How could I best do this? Go via Help -> install new Software or via sudo apt-get ...?

Greatful for help on this issue

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Kepler? Why Kepler. Install [Mars](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). **;)**

Use an extra distribution for C/C++ ([Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-cpp-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)) and one for Java ([Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)).

That prepares you definitely less problems. Both languages in one development environment faces a number of traps. Believe me.

Read my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/656569/367165) for further instructions.

Comment: ok thanks :- will look this up and may accept :)